# VBA code to sort by date, then text, then colour (and updating on cell change)

Tags: excel, vba

As above, I am looking to create VBA code to sort one column by its date, then another column by its text, and then a final column by its colour. There are 5 colours to sort by, which I found a code to use, however, couldn't work out a way to combine each of the different functions.

It is essentially a large list of names with different assignments (text sort), which have different deadlines (date sort). Then I have set up conditional formatting to change row a certain colour depending on what is entered, for example "Complete" turns the row green, which is where I want the colour sort to come into play.

This is essentially what I am trying to accomplish, but where the sort automatically updates when a cell within a range has been edited (or a macro):

[Default sorting order using excels sort feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgrKp.png)

The code I have tried successfully sorts the date, and runs once again once cell updates within the 5th column, however, struggling to implement the other sort functions. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

  If Target.Column = 5 Then

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A160:M" & lastRow).Sort key1: Range("E160:E" & lastRow),order1: xlAscending, Header:=xlNo 

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try using the macro recorder?

Comment: @Sorceri I did not. Is there anywhere you know I can read up on this / get some guidance? I am pretty new to VBA so my apologies.

Comment: In Excel, Right click the Ribbon and select Customize The Ribbon.  When that opens, place a check mark on the developer section.  You should now see the Developer tab in Excel.   Click the tab, click the button to record the macro.  Go do your sort, then go back to the developer tab and click stop recording.  Click Visual Basics on the developer tab to open the editor.  You should see a module1 which will have the recorded macro and code for your sort.

Comment: @Sorceri Top man! That was much more simplified that I what I was trying to do. Guess you have to take a step back sometimes haha. Thanks a lot :)